# sqlalchemy ORM : how to declare a table class that contains multiple key?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm a newbie in Sqlalchemy. 
I have a table with multiple key in column USERNAME. 
This is what I've done in my model.

Model:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root@localhost/admin'
db = SQLAlchemy(app) 

class RADUSAGE(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'RADUSAGE'
    USERNAME = db.Column(db.String(513))
    AGE = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, USERNAME, AGE):
       self.USERNAME = USERNAME
       self.AGE = AGE

def __repr__(self):
    return '<RADUSAGE %r>' % self.USERNAME
```

But I got an error:

```
File "/Users/admin/rad_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 530, in map
 **self.mapper_args
File "<string>", line 2, in mapper
File "/Users/admin/rad_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 677, in __init__
self._configure_pks()
File "/Users/admin/rad_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1277, in _configure_pks
(self, self.mapped_table.description))
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|RADUSAGE|RADUSAGE could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'RADUSAGE'
```

How can I declare this table class that contains multiple key in sqlalchemy? Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean a composite primary key? Or multiple unique constraints?

Comment: I mean, multiple key where the column is the first column of a nonunique index in which multiple occurrences of a given value are permitted within the column. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)

Comment: So just a regular index? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I just want to know how can I declare the multiple key in sqlalchemy. I tried not to put any key in USERNAME, but I got error (looking for the primary key). I also tried to put it in primary key and yes, I got one row but based on database, I should have 4 results.

Comment: Please include what you've done in your question. Add the SQLAlchemy model you have and possible operations you've tried. Keep it minimal though; don't dump all of your code, just the parts that matter. Include a small set of sample data and what you'd expect as a result. Note that linking to images of code, table definitions and such is shunned upon. Code is text, and images cannot be searched or copied to editors.

Comment: "I tried not to put any key in USERNAME, but I got error (looking for the primary key)." sounds like you're trying to map the table in the image to SQLAlchemy ORM, and chose the *USERNAME* column as the primary key candidate even though it is not unique (it just has a regular index on it). Read [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key) on mapping tables without a primary key. You get only 1 row as a result, because you lied to the ORM. It expects the given primary key candidate to be **unique**.

Comment: ...It returns only 1 result since it looks at the 3 other rows and sees the same USERNAME and discards them because it already has a result with that primary key. Note that this is speculation until you provide the model definitions etc.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. ORM models [must have a unique key per instance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key). You can on the other hand use [Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/) and [`Table`s](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#metadata-describing) to access your table.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify primary_key=true in your mapping for each PK column:

```
USERNAME = db.Column(db.String(513), primary_key=True)
AGE = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Did you try that?